# How should I file my taxes as a contractor?

Tags: income-tax, canada, self-employment, ontario, contractor

For background, I'm an Ontario, Canada resident, and I've worked here during all of FY2016.

For the first time, in addition to mostly doing full-time work as an employee of a company, I did just over 5 months of work as an independent contractor. During this time, I made less than $30k providing services in the private sector; this means that I qualified as a [small supplier](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/glssry-eng.html#smallsupplier) under the CRA's definition, and that my registration for an HST number is voluntary. I do not have an HST number as a result.

With tax season right around the corner, I'd like to know what to look out for (which forms I should/shouldn't fill out, mostly) aside from the normal forms one would fill out when receiving their T4 slips from "normal" work done outside of independent contracts.

Answer (score 1):

For tax purposes you will need to file **as an employee** (T4 slips and tax withheld automatically), but **also as an entrepreneur**. I had the same situation myself last year. [Employee and self-employed](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tg/rc4110/rc4110-e.html) is a publication from Revenue Canada that will help you.

You need to fill out the [statement of business activity](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/t2125/t2125-16e.pdf) form and keep detailed records of all your deductible expenses. **Make photocopies and keep them 7 years**.

May I suggest you take an accountant to file your income tax form. More expensive but makes you less susceptible to receive Revenue Canada inspectors for a check-in.

If you can read french, you can [use this simple spreadsheet](http://www.conseiller.ca/nouvelles/limpot-des-conseillers-un-outil-gratuit-pour-se-simplifier-la-vie-58051) for your expenses. Your accountant will be happy.